# android using MultipartEntity upload files to server throw exceptions

Tags: android, upload, multipart

I want to upload files to the server, using libs httpcore-4.3.2 httpclient-4.3.3 httpmime-4.3.3. But there still exceptions.I am not sure whether is the problem of my code or the libs versrion Here is my code.

```
    public boolean uploadVideoToServer(String fileName, String title, String description, String iEndpointURI)
        {
             boolean retBool = false;

             try {

             HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(iEndpointURI);
             httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
             httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + usnHeader);

             //HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

             File file = new File(fileName);
             MultipartEntityBuilder mpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create(); 
             mpEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

             //ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "video/*");
             FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "video/*");

             mpEntity.addTextBody("title", title);
             mpEntity.addTextBody("description", description);
             mpEntity.addPart("original_file", fileBody);
             httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity.build());
             System.out.println("executing request x " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
             response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

             Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Location");
             for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                 System.out.println("Location: "+headers[i].getValue());}



             if (resEntity != null) {
               resEntity.consumeContent();
               System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
               retBool = true;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());

            }

        return retBool;
     }
    }

exceptions are these:

    03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at com.uu.serg.pia.backend.RESTConsumer.uploadVideoToStickyworld(RESTConsumer.java:429)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at com.uu.serg.pia.backend.StickyworldConsumer.uploadVideoFile(StickyworldConsumer.java:61)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at com.uu.serg.pia.activities.UploadVideoForm$UploadAsyncTask.doInBackground(UploadVideoForm.java:139)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at com.uu.serg.pia.activities.UploadVideoForm$UploadAsyncTask.doInBackground(UploadVideoForm.java:1)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-19 15:29:17.851: E/AndroidRuntime(8001):     ... 3 more
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001): Activity com.uu.serg.pia.activities.UploadVideoForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42d50ea0 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-1110,229} that was originally added here
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.uu.serg.pia.activities.UploadVideoForm has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42d50ea0 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-1110,229} that was originally added here
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at com.uu.serg.pia.activities.UploadVideoForm$UploadAsyncTask.onPreExecute(UploadVideoForm.java:132)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at com.uu.serg.pia.activities.UploadVideoForm.initUpload(UploadVideoForm.java:86)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 15:29:18.291: E/WindowManager(8001):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think that has nothing to do with the code you showed us. The Exception is of another kind.

Comment: do you know what kind of exception?

Comment: I don't know what line number is this:              System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
Maybe you should check what gets here. Since other call to System.out.println should always get a string.